# Phonegap build issue with Plugins

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-build

My first here .. for last week i have this problem with phonegap build ..

**My plugin tab doesnt catch any plugins added !!**

for last week searched every single site .. doesnt have any answer ..

i have tried everything with plugins CLI way , Phonegap build , npm and gpb

add the xmlns:gap .. changing the version but also issue with phonegap build with this want to change to 3.5 it went always 3.7 or 3.3 !! and search for plugins that working with phonegap version didnt working also -_-

Dont know what even to do more ..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.my.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">   
<gap:plugin name="com.performanceactive.plugins.camera" version="1.4" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.3" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.2" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" version="0.2.11" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.3.3" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" version="0.2.11" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.13" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />

<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <param name="android-package" value="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera" src=" https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.logilite.vision.camera" version="0.2.11" src = " https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git"/>
    <gap:plugin name=" https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git" version="0.2.11" />

</feature>
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.example">
    <param name="APIKey" value="12345678" />
    <param name="APISecret" value="12345678" />
</gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin name="com.logilite.vision.camera" version="0.2.11" />
<gap:plugin name="com.logilite.vision.camera" version="0.2.11" src = " https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git"/>
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" src = "npm" />

cordova-plugin-camera
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

and there is another try ..

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
    version = "1.0.0">
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="com.logilite.vision.camera" version="0.2.11" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved it .. The normal tree for the program is

-WWW

-Platform

-Config.xml

when you move the **config.xml** to the **WWW** your Plugins will reads Normally ..